# Returning a value depending on the type of the template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have a working bidirectional map (one-to-one mapping) class as follows:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class BiMap
{
public:
    void insert(const T1& a, const T2& b);
private:
    std::map<T1, T2*> map1_;
    std::map<T2, T1*> map2_;
};
```

I have been able to implement the `insert` function. Now I want to implement a `retrieve` function such that if user passes value of type `T1` say `t1`, it'll return `*map1_[t1]` and similarly if they pass value of type `T2` say `t2`, it'll return `*map2_[t2]`. It is guaranteed that type `T1` will not be the same as type `T2` so how can I make it return a value by checking it's type?

Comment: Is the intent that you only want to write a single `retrieve` function, and not have to implement two different functions that both *nearly* do the same thing?

Comment: @Xirema yeah I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Side note: if on C++11 or greater, you probably want to `static_assert(!std::is_same<T1, T2>)` because if `T1` and `T2` are the same type, any implementation of `retrieve()` that uses overloading/templates is either going to cause a compilation error, or only retrieve from one of the two maps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can use C++17 your retrieve function would look like

```
template <typename T>
auto retrieve(T const& key)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, T1> || std::is_same_v<T, T2>, "Key type is not in map");
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, T1>)
        return *map1_.at(key); // or whatever you actually want to return
    else
        return *map2_.at(key); // or whatever you actually want to return
}
```

If you can't use C++17 then I would just write 2 overloads like

```
auto retrieve(T1 const& key)
{
    return *map1_.at(key); // or whatever you actually want to return
}
auto retrieve(T2 const& key)
{
    return *map2_.at(key); // or whatever you actually want to return
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you. I'm using C++14. Is there any advantage of using the former over the latter?

Comment: @lucieon Personally I like the two overloads solution since it is shorter and easier to understand.  It also lets your code compile on more implementations.  Typically I would only use the the first way if there would be more then a handful of overloads.

Comment: Templates also generally imply that the set of acceptable types is infinite in size, even if constrained. There are _only two possible types_ here, so using an overload is more appropriate.